# Start adding children from right in Row

Tags: dart, flutter

I am designing an app in Flutter. I want to add elements from Right side rather than default left. Please guide how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the text direction.

```
    Row(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            color: Colors.green,
          )
        ],
      )
```

---

Example 2 with text

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text("one"),
      Text("two"),
      Text("three"),
    ],
  )
```